# tkinter spinbox double zeroes

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a spinbox that needs to have double zeroes, like a clock.  No matter what I try, I get only 1.  Is it even possible to have a spinbox display double zeroes?

```
# all give same options: 0 - 15 - 30 - 45
Spinbox(root, from_=00, to=45, increment=15)
Spinbox(root, values=('00', '15', '30', '45'))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Entirely possible!
Use the `format=` option.

```
Spinbox(root, from_=00, to=45, increment=15, format="%02.0f")
```

That should give you what you need. Take a look at the [format docs for more information.](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/format.htm#M23)

Answer (score 0):

Now u need to use [format()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/format) before

*Example in 3.7 :*

```
var = IntVar(root)
var.set("{:02d}".format(time.localtime().tm_sec))
spinbox = ttk.Spinbox(root, textvariable=var, from_=0, to=23, width = 2, format="%02.0f")
```